# Warning while executing make install with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, python-3.6

I downloaded python 3.6 and trying to do the usual `./configure && make install`

I got  these warning:

```
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c: In function 'classify_argument':
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:195:18: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'else' statement [-Wempty-body]
    FFI_ASSERT (0);
                  ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:224:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
                ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:245:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
                    ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:264:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      for (i = 1; i < words; i++)
                    ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:270:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
                ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c: In function 'examine_argument':
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:323:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                 ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c: In function 'ffi_call':
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:484:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++, a += 8, size -= 8)
                  ^
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c: In function 'ffi_closure_unix64_inner':
/usr/src/Python-3.6.0/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.c:659:18: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++, a += 8)
                  ^
```

Are something I need to handle with care?

Comment: Are you a C programmer and working on the python interpreter itself? If not, these warnings are not for you and there's not much you can do.

Comment: So, do they will cause me NO trouble ... or ... ?

Comment: Hm, I see you've opened an issue on the tracker :-) You might also be interested in https://bugs.python.org/issue25077 which might be a duplicate.

Comment: My issue was closed as resolved, lol.... an author told me: "Building _ctypes with the bundled copy of libffi is deprecated since Python 3.6, and is not possible in 3.7. If you need the ctypes module, please install libffi separately and make sure the Python build process can find it. If you build libffi yourself, please report any warnings at github.com/libffi/libffi." ... I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved installing these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev
```

Then I can install Python 3.6 as I usually do:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.0    
wget "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz" \
  && tar xzf "Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz" \
  && cd "Python-$PYTHON_VERSION" \
  && ./configure > /dev/null \
  && make altinstall > /dev/null
```

For sake of documentation: I used altinstall to keep Python 2.7 (pre-installed on ubuntu 16.10) and be able to use Python 3.x.

I can invoice "old" python:

```
python
```

Or new python

```
python3.6
```